# How to export comma delimited csv file using google drive Api

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using google drive api to export file

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FileID/export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.google-apps.document
```

i want exported file columns comma delimited, how can I get it using api ? 
Like exported file column values are "test" "abc" "hexa"

Comment: if the commas arnt in the file already i dont think it will add them this will only work if its a googlesheet.   Try text/csv

Answer (score 0):

You should probably go look at the [Google Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads), specifically the portion labeled "Downloading Google Documents". Using `files.export` allows you to define the MIME type of your export data.

Comment: I've searched everywhere but I didn't found method that'd include commas around returning  value from google drive api request ..